# Javascript add and remove eventlistner

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a set of circles (.dot), and when we click one of them it animates another element.

I am trying to set it up so that when one of these circles is clicked, then the mouseover, mouseout and click functions would be inactive for this *one* item.

I need to use addEventListener and then removeEventListener or something similar, but I am having trouble implementing where this should be setup in the code.

This code pen shows what I mean: https://codepen.io/celli/pen/MMwpjx

For this example I removed my addEventListner on the click function, since it was not working for me, and I am implementing it incorrectly.

```
// mouseover and mouseout functions
$('.dotWrapper').mouseover(function(event) {
 TweenMax.to($(this).children('.dot'), .25,{scale:3, ease: Circ.easeOut, 
transformOrigin:"50% 50%"});
        });

$('.dotWrapper').mouseout(function(event) {
 TweenMax.to($(this).children('.dot'), .75,{scale:1, ease: Circ.easeOut});
        });

// click function animates
$('.dotWrapper').click(function() {
  TweenMax.to($(this).children('.dot'), .25,{scale:2, ease: Circ.easeOut});
   $('.dot').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).children('.dot').addClass('selected');

  // clear existing lines and dates
   TweenMax.to('.vertLine', .5, {alpha: 0, scaleY:1, ease:Expo.easeOut});
  TweenMax.to('.timelineDate', .5, {alpha: 0, y:-20, ease:Expo.easeOut});

  // animate the date and line
var dateLine = new TimelineMax({ });
  dateLine.to($(this).children('.vertLine'), 1.2, {scaleY:.50,autoAlpha: 1,ease:Expo.easeOut})
          .to($(this).children('.timelineDate'), 1, {autoAlpha: 1,y:20,ease:Expo.easeOut}, '-=1');
        });
```

Comment: No, don’t try to remove and add event handlers all the time. Set some sort of flag on the element (f.e. using https://api.jquery.com/data/) when it is clicked - and then check that flag in your other event handler functions, to determine whether those should actually do something.

Comment: @04FS can you show me an example of what you mean using my code?

Comment: An “example” based on your code would be more or less the full-fledged solution already … try something yourself first, please. Instead of .data(), you can also just add/remove a class, if that’s easier. So, add a class, `active` or something, in your click handler. In every handler function you want to “pause”, check if the element has that class first - if so, do nothing.

Comment: Since you want to pause your click handler itself as well, you need to find a way to remove that class again, when your TweenMax animations on the element have finished. Guess that library should provide its own events for that, check docs.

Comment: @04FS I added if (!$('.dot').hasClass("selected")) { to my mouseover function to check if the element does not have the class of 'selected' but I don't see it working. maybe there's another way to say doesNotHaveClass

Comment: Why `.dot`, your event handlers are bound to `.dotWrapper`. And you don’t want to check if the _first_ `.dotWrapper` element in the page has that class, but the _current_ one. So use `$(this)`, instead of selecting the element to check by class.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you can use `.one()` instead of `.click()`

Comment: If I use that I will not be able to click it again, (which we need to do) after that item is inactive again. -- Also, using that will not disengage my mouseover and mouseout events for that already clicked item. .one( "click", function() {